# Spring dependency injection with WildFly

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, wildfly, weld

I have a web application (war file) that depends (Maven) on another project (jar file) that uses Spring for dependency injection. So in that other project I have a couple of xml files to declare my beans, in my case business objects. I started using WildFly instead of Tomcat/Jetty and apparently there is that thing called Weld in charge of DI. My web app doesn't use Spring (for now), it's just a simple Jersey RESTful API.
I want my business objects to be injectable (@Inject) in my resources (controllers).

How do I make my beans accessible, meaning how do we mix Spring DI and WildFly DI?

Right now in my web app project I have a WEB-INF/beans.xml file with this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:weld="http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd
    http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans_1_1.xsd
    bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

But when I try to deploy, for this code:

```
@Inject SomeBO myBO;
```

I get this error:

> WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type SomeBO with qualifiers @Default

Thanks.

**EDIT**
I need to import my beans with the xml files, I don't want to annotate them, for instance I have a bo.xml file (Spring beans) that contains such declaration:

```
    <bean id="com.xxx.bo.SomeBO" parent="com.xxx.bo._AbstractBO">
        <property name="target">
            <bean class="com.xxx.bo.SomeBOImpl">
                <property name="DAO" ref="com.xxx.dao.SomeDAO"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

WildFly implements the Java EE Spec which means it provides an implementation for [CDI](http://cdi-spec.org/). In WildFly's case it uses the reference implementation which is Weld. There are some [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giwhb.html) for Java EE 6 that should explain CDI fairly well.

As far as your error, you probably just need to annotate your your SomBO implementation with `@Named` or a valid CDI annotation to make it a CDI managed bean.

Comment: See my edit, I need to use the xml declaration, meaning I need to make WildFly/Weld aware of those files.

Comment: They might have to be annotated to use CDI. To be honest I'm not sure what goes in the beans.xml file so maybe it's configurable there.